# Retrieve logs from azure application insight in c#

Tags: c#, azure, monitoring

I need to retrieve logs (traces, exceptions, requests) from azure application insights in c#. For that I have to use the API provided by App insights. I found in this blog [enter link description here](https://zimmergren.net/retrieve-logs-from-application-insights-programmatically-with-net-core-c/) a way to do that using the package Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights but it's deprecated. Other alternatives for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100878/alternative-to-https-www-nuget-org-packages-microsoft-azure-applicationinsight)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DeepDave-Mt, Yes the Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights is deprecated and there is new version released [NuGet Gallery | Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query/)

According to [Microsoft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger) it says,

> you can use [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights)
> You can use Ilogger and telemetry for logging using application insights

***References:***

[c# - Alternative to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights/ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100878/alternative-to-https-www-nuget-org-packages-microsoft-azure-applicationinsight)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-trace-logs

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-application-insights-for-exception-logging-in-c-sharp/