# How to fetch records from the azure application insights using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I need to fetch records from Azure application insights using C#.

I have tried using the below approach, but it requires an app service to be created in Azure and I want to avoid it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-azure-ad-api

I have also followed this answer as well, OP has suggested using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Monitor.Query but it looks very old, so I would like to know if is this still valid.

[Alternative to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100878/alternative-to-https-www-nuget-org-packages-microsoft-azure-applicationinsight)

So I am confused, Could you please help me with the correct approach? My requirement is not to create any extra resources in Azure and wants to fetch from app insights using C#.

Comment: Please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76529407/19648279).

Comment: @Harshitha I don't want to configure app insights. It's already there. I just want to fetch lets app insights using my C# code. so for example it should fetch the result of the query `traces | where cloud_RoleName == "someService"`

Comment: Ok.Yes,AFAIK,the Nuget Package `Azure.Monitor.Query` is still valid.If it is not supported they would have updated the package as deprecated.

Comment: Both the packages work.`Azure.Monitor.Query` can be used if you want to query complex queries.And if you want to go for a basic and simple queries suggest you to use `Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights`.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `Application Insights` configured, you can query the data as long as you [configure a workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource).

For example, once a workspace is configured, a generic method like below can be used to query against a `WorkspaceId`:

```
private async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string query, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var response = await _client.QueryWorkspaceAsync<T>(_options.WorkspaceId, query, new QueryTimeRange(timeSpan));

    return response.Value;
}
```

where `_client` is:

`Azure.Montitor.Query.LogsQueryClient _client;`

An example query could be as such:

```
public async Task<int> GetFailedViewCount()
{
    var query = $"AppEvents" +
        $"| extend Output = tostring(Properties[\"Output\"]) " +
        $"| where Output contains (\"Failed to execute internal view\")" +
        $"| summarize Count=count()";

    var response = await QueryAsync<int>(query, TimeSpan.FromHours(48));

    return response.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

where we have a `CustomEvent` (in application insights) which becomes an `AppEvent` in Workspace, which has been created from a docker container.

Comment: Resource mode is Classic not workspace based.